# How to Deploy .NET 7 Desktop app to my Windows machine?

Tags: deployment, desktop, .net-7.0

I use .NET Framework 4.7 at work, but on my home machine I attempted .NET 7.

I got all through the process of building and debugging my app, executing it many times in the debugger, then created a release version, copied it (a single, standalone executable) to the directory where I wanted it to live--and then found out it didn't run. Double-click on the EXE file, and nothing happens.

The build process for .NET 7 also produced a DLL for some reason, and in case it's necessary, I copied it into my destination folder as well. (Maybe the DLL is the real app, and the .EXE file just loads it? I can't get rid of the DLL even with the PublishSingleFile option in my project file.) Now when I double-click on the EXE, I get a popup saying that I need the .NET 7 Windows host framework, and would I like to install it now? Click Yes and NOTHING HAPPENS.

So I went to Microsoft's .NET website and clicked through many links to find the .NET 7 installer for 64-bit Windows. Download its huge install package, extract it to a new folder, run *dotnet.exe* as Administrator--and NOTHING HAPPENS.

I don't understand why something so obvious has now been made difficult, but in this instance I was able to easily just give up and redo the program using .NET Framework 4.7.

Eventually I'll have to move on to .NET 7 or 8. Can anyone point me to concise instructions on what you do to enable your .NET 7 Windows Desktop app to *actually run* on a Windows desktop computer?